# Why the line-height of the Bootstrap navbar-brand hover isn't change?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover, navbar

I use Bootstrap to make my navbar and then, I decide to increase the line-height of the navbar by 50px.

When I add the :hover, all the links' hover work fine, except for the navbar-brand which still have the original Bootstrap line-height.

```css
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
 line-height: 50px !important;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #0ff !important;
}

.navbar-brand:hover{
 line-height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
   </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Please check in the expand snippet instead.